# In a Mercurial repository, change working folder to be a sub-folder

Tags: linux, apache, mercurial

I think the answer to this question is that you can't, but I wanted to ask the question in case I was just unable to find the answer.

In additon, I wanted to know if there is a better way of dealing with this situation.

I have a repository that has a sub-folder named website. The problem is that the developer that is working on the website wants to check files in and out of the linux /var/www/html folder.

The problem is that the root of the hg repo is not the website. If I check out in html then you end up with /var/www/html/website (plus whatever other files and folders that we in the repo root are now in the html folder).

If this was SVN, then I could just do a checkout of the website subfolder.

One thought I had was that there might be a way to change working folder of this clone to be the website folder (kindof like an SVN Switch). It seems like it should technicaly be possible since the actual repository is stoed in the .hg folder but I didn't see anything like that in the docs.

On the other hand, is there a better way to handle this situation? One thought was to clone the hg repo to a neutral location and configure Apache to load the website from there, but the dev working on this has reasons why this wouldn't be the best solution.

Are there other ways to handle this? What are the normal workflows/patterns for working with Apache websites and HG? Is it more normal to configure apache. I usually work in Windows/IIS and this is what I would have done.

Are there other situations with HG where you really just want to work in a subfolder. What is the solution there?

Comment: just wanted to add.. the 2 solutions that I'm considering are (1) re-organize the repo so that the website files are in the root and keep the other files in a seperate repo or (2) change the website folder into a sub-repo but I don't have any experience working with subrepos, yet.

Comment: How about using a symlink or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a symbolic link for this, e.g.:

ln -s /path/to/repo/website /var/www/html

This approach allows you to setup your system (apache, etc) once, and quickly swap to different code bases. There are more sophisticated ways to do this, but this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I second the symlink. This works well for managing multiple folders in one repo on Windows too with mklink.